# QComboBox different Item value when selected and in dropDown

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qt4.8, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

**how to easily make duo QAbstractListModel × QComboBox (not reimplementing QComboBox)**

so that item representation on selection differs from one on DropDownList

**Background:**

I have model (inherited from **QAbstractListModel**) which flattens other model derived **QAbstractItemModel**, which however represents **tree** structure

Items are in the same order as they are in the tree model

I wanted to indent them, for better orientation in selection,

however once selected, it looks strange, when the sole **selected** item is indented

i.e.  having this structure (verbatim how I assume it being seen in QComboBox **DropDown** list

```
parent 1
 -> child 1.1
 ---> subChild 1.1.1
 -> child 1.2
 -> child 1.3
 ---> subChild 1.3.1
 ---> subChild 1.3.2
parent2
```

and once **selected**, I want it to show only

```
subChild 1.3.2
```

now it shows

---> subChild 1.3.2

as far as I know, both representations go through model::data(index, role=Qt::DisplayRole), so I can't differentiate them there

PS: In case there is some QComboBox-like directly working with models containing trees, even better

Comment: basically you want to remove indentation on an item when it is selected?

Comment: basically yes,
just that the item name is without indentation, indentation is constructed on data() call when asking for Qt::DisplayRole